# get TKey and TValue

Tags: c#, dictionary

i have a dictionary ...

```
IDictionary<int, dynamic> paragraphs = new Dictionary<int, dynamic>
            {
                [1] = new Nr1(),
                [2] = new Nr2()
            };
```

... first of all i don't want the value " Nr1 ", or " Nr2 ". I need to get those specifiers -> i mean the int and dynamic.

i want to make a "global foreach" so that i don't have to always specify "string", "int" or "dynamic" in the KeyValuePair part.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please reformulate the question? Give some examples, clarify what's wrong right now? I didn't understand your question at all.

Comment: This sounds very much like a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What is the intended purpose of that mysterious "global foreach" you briefly mentioned? (If you don't want to specify the type of keys and values, how would you access any possible field/property/method members of the keys or values in your "global foreach" without using clunky, cumbersome and slow reflection?)

Comment: I strongly suspect that whatever you want to use your "global foreach" for, there is already a Linq method allowing you to do more or less the same with much less pain. But i am just guessing here, of course...

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question. But couldn't you use a Object instead of dynamic? that way you could parse it dinamicaly inside your foreach....

Comment: i need to get ' dynamic ' and ' int '. then if possible i'd like to do a foreach that will work for every dictionary. so : foreach(KeyValuePair<firstSpecifyer,secondSpecifier> in paragraphs){}

Comment: as elgonzo already mentioned: what do you intend to do in that global foreach?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'll be guessing here - use `var`:

```
foreach(var item in paragraphs) 
{
    (...)
}
```